# Postman not sending nested JSON data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman, rest

I've been sending data to my mongoose sub-document the same way for weeks. Last night both postman and insomnia stopped sending nested data in post request, but post requests work fine on the client side...

Below you can see that any nested data does not get sent in the request.
I didn't change anything in the postman and insomnia settings and I'm pretty sure that I'm sending the data the way I always was

[image: Postman]

Mongoose Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ProgramSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  programName: String,
});
const NameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: { type: String },
  lastName: { type: String },
  middleIn: { type: String },
});

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: [NameSchema],
  username: { type: String },
  age: { type: String },
  programs: [ProgramSchema],
  avatar: { type: String },
  email: { type: String },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
    default:
      "https://www.minervastrategies.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/default-avatar.jpg",
  },
  tier: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});

module.exports = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code is at fault.  When more than one tool fails, doubt your code not the tool :) You are specifying an [array schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) `name: [NameSchema]` and instead sending an object for `name`. Same for everything else.

Comment: My client side is fine though, when I go in the app on my phone (Expo Go react-native) and create a user from there, all the data is captured and sent in the request.

Comment: Maybe, `programs` should be an array of objects instead of a single object?

Comment: Tried that already, also same thing for `name`